# Workflow for pushing Node.js app to dev/prod servers

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Node.js Express app that I'm hosting on Nodejitsu. I'm already using `env` switches in Express for `dev` and `prod`, but obviously I'm going to need to push to different `dev` and `prod` servers.

For Nodejitsu, pushing to these servers requires a simple `jitsu deploy`, which looks to my `package.json` for app and domain/subdomain information.

I'm trying to think of the best way to handle the various pushes to `dev` and `prod` (and/r perhaps `testing`, `staging`, etc. in the future) given the `package.json` restriction. Clearly I would like to avoid maintaining several git repos, each with its own slightly different `package.json`.

What kind of workflow would be ideal for handling this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are't using Jitsu, but what we do is keep a couple of different version of the confs around in a confs folder. When we go to deploy our scripts copy the appropriate conf/package.json file in to the root dir.

You may be interested in this: https://github.com/nodejitsu/jitsu/issues/134

As Małecki points out in that issue, this can be done with npm scripts. You can have a few script setup in the package.json file(s) that do the appropriate pre-deploy work.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond to this. Is your process still the same? Do you use any bash scripts to ease this process or is it all manual? I deploy so often I can see this becoming really grating.

Comment: When I need to run more then a single line to perform a deployment I try to work it in to a bash script. Then I add it to the scripts part of the package.json file. This way I only need to do `npm run-script deploy_production`.